# Rounded font design in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

In SwiftUI you can do this to get rounded design of the system font:

```
Text("Your Text").font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))
```

How do I achieve the same with Flutter on platforms where rounded design is available?

Comment: What do you mean by rounded font design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you would need to include the 'SF Pro Rounded Regular' font in your project's assets, and then make use of it as a custom font.

The [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) have a good walkthrough of this process.

That said, it is worth taking a moment to read over the License terms for using the "Apple Font", which can be found in Font Book.

`You may use the Apple Font solely for creating mock-ups of user interfaces to be used in software products running on Apple’s iOS, iPadOS, macOS or tvOS operating systems, as applicable. The foregoing right includes the right to show the Apple Font in screen shots, images, mock-ups or other depictions, digital and/or print, of such software products running solely on iOS, macOS or tvOS.`

[image: Font Book - SF Pro Rounded Regular]